# Why does java native HashMap in clojure run slowly?

Tags: java, clojure, hashmap

I associate a key to a hash map for 10000000 time. Here's the Java code and output：

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> mp = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        long  start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            mp.put(1, 1);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + (end - start) + " msecs");
    }
}


$ javac TestMap.java && java -cp . TestMap
Elapsed time: 38 msecs
```

And then I call java from clojure in REPL:

```
user=> (import java.util.HashMap)
java.util.HashMap
user=> (def mp (HashMap.))
#'user/mp
user=>  (time (dotimes [n 10000000] (.put mp 1 1)))
"Elapsed time: 10024.797 msecs"
nil
```

Both code do the same thing, but the clojure version runs exstreamly slow!!

What's the problem?

Comment: BTW  awesome how this is only 3 lines (and much easier to read) in Clojure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

add type hint is better:

```
user> (import 'java.util.HashMap)
java.util.HashMap
user> (def mp (HashMap.))
#'user/mp
user> (time (dotimes [n 10000000] (.put mp 1 1)))
"Elapsed time: 13932.248126 msecs"
nil
user> (time (dotimes [n 10000000] (.put ^HashMap mp 1 1)))
"Elapsed time: 117.915992 msecs"
nil
```

Comment: For more on type hints, see http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Type%20Hints

Answer (score 9):

The first step with performance problems like this is to turn on reflection warnings and remove any.

```
 (set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
```

Also loop and recur have the lowest overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also increase Java code speed  with declaring HashMap size in declaration

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> mp = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(10000000);
```

I guess it is a also a way for REPL (I do not know it), is it possible to reserve memory space?

Comment: This is true, but doesn't make much difference in this case - the real problem is with the reflection